# How to read metafiles of NTFS file system using C

Tags: c++, c, windows, ntfs, ntfs-mft

Can anyone show me how to directly access metafiles ($MFT, $Volume, $Bitmap...) ?
I need to get info from these files.

Comment: There are many solutions that can be found on google http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081531/extract-bitmap-file-from-ntfs-image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310120/how-to-dump-the-ntfs-bitmap-file http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/154707/Reading-the-mft-file-from-an-NTFS-drive https://tzworks.net/prototype_page.php?proto_id=12

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920243/dumping-the-content-of-the-mft-file?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652135/reading-mft-in-ntfs?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ioctl function, [FSCTL_GET_NTFS_FILE_RECORD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364568.aspx).